# Data is not properly being accepted

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, axios

I'm trying to do a POST request with axios to this API:
http://apis.paralleldots.com/text_docs/index.html#emotion

I get a status 200 for calling the API but it says "Parameter `API Key`  or `TEXT` is either not specified or set to null."

Am I calling the POST request properly? I'm following what I see in other examples and documentations for axios

I did also try `"Content-Type":"application/json"` but this returns an error:

> has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:

It does not have HTTP ok status.

```
api() {
      var text = this.text;
      var api_key = "XXXXXXXXX";
      var lang_code = "en";

      axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://apis.paralleldots.com/v5/emotion",
        data: {
          text: text,
          api_key: api_key,
          lang_code: lang_code
        },
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
        }
      })
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

Comment: "Content-Type" : "application/json"

Comment: Also try it without lang_code

Comment: I've tried the application/json but then it gives me an error with CORS

Comment: I ran your request locally and it is returning a 200, however the body is containing a code: 400, which means the api probably isn't sending the code properly. ``` data: { code: 400, message: 'Parameter `API Key` or `TEXT` is either not specified or set to null.' }
```
Something about your body is malformed, I can't really say since I don't know the API specification, but yeah the API is saying it's a bad request, so I'd investigate that.